# Summation operator convention

Tags: probability, summation

I am trying to figure out how I can play around with summation operators when one of the terms inside the operator is a probability. For example in the below I want to figure out how I can combine the two terms that include $$Q(\tau > T_i)$$ together…. So I can find a form $$Q(\tau > T_n)=$$

From the following expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{C}{M} \cdot D(0, T_i) \cdot Q(\tau > T_i) + F \cdot D(0, T_n) \cdot Q(\tau > T_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} F \cdot (1 + \frac{C}{M}) \cdot \text{rec} \cdot D(0, T_n) \cdot [Q(\tau > T_{i-1}) - Q(\tau > T_i)]$$

In this example: F, M, C and rec are constants.

The function $$ D(0, T_n)$$ represents some function which applies from time 0 to n where n is the “end time”. If the subscript i is used for this function it denotes the part of the function that can apply to the increment. It typically is if the form exponential ^ (constant)*t, the constant can itself here instead be a function. We make no assumptions.

Finally, $$Q(\tau > T_i)$$ all Qs represent a probability of an event occurring, with n it is the “survival probability” till end time, with i again for the increment. In the problem you specifically need to survive to time i-1 to survive to i.

Sorry for the lack of clarity and some typing mistakes earlier. Thank you!

Comment: It would help to explain some of your terms better, especially since you have $T_n$ indexed in the sums but $T$ and $T_i$ and $T_{i-1}$ also appear.

Comment: Thanks I will update within the question itself!